# How to create a generic data flow in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to build a generic data flow using parameters to specifiy the columns names.

I can use byName within "Filter", "Join" and "Derived Columns", but get the following error when using byName in "Window":-
[image]

For example byName('xxxx') works fine in the previous steps but fails in "Window".

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using byName() directly in the over clause, use a Derived Column prior to your Window transformation and set the name of the column using byName() there. Call the new column something like columnForMyOverClause. Then pick columnForMyOverClause in the Window transformation.